# Why does a const-qualifier warning depend on variable content, not type?

Tags: c, string, gcc

I found a strange behavior from `gcc` with the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char str[] = "This string contains é which is a multi-byte character";
    const char search[] = "Ʃ";
    char * pos = strstr(str, search);
    printf("%s\n", pos);

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler produces a warning:

```
$ gcc toto.c -std=c99
toto.c: In function ‘main’:
toto.c:8:18: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier
from pointer target type [enabled by default]
```

But if I change the content of `search`:

```c
const char search[] = "é";
```

The very same compilation does not throw any warning: why?

**Note:** I have the exact same behavior if I swap `Ʃ` and `é`: if the character in `search` is not present in `str`, I get the warning.

Comment: As a note: `strstr` returns a null pointer if the substring isn’t found, and a null pointer cannot be passed to `printf` with `%s`.

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main(void)`. If you're using a textbook that tells you to use `void main()`, get rid of it and find a better one; its author does not know C well enough to be teaching it. (`void main()` can be acceptable to some implementations, but it is at best non-portable.) Can you tell us where you got the idea that `void main()` is acceptable in C?

Comment: Agree, this is unacceptable ! I usually don't write `main` like that, this is my `toto.c` test-file lazy-coded. I'll fix that.

Comment: @KeithThompson Can you tell us where you got the idea that this was supposed to be a question about how to write a production-strength main routine? ;-)

Comment: @jlehr: If I had thought that was what the question was about, I would have posted that as an answer, not as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in gcc, corrected in a later release.

Here's a small program I've written to illustrate the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    const char message[] = "hello";
#ifdef ASCII_ONLY
    const char search_for[] = "h";
#else
    const char search_for[] = "Ʃ";
#endif
    char *non_const_message = strstr(message, search_for);
    if (non_const_message == NULL) {
        puts("non_const_message == NULL");
    }
    else {
        puts(non_const_message);
    }
}
```

When I compile this with

```
gcc -DASCII_ONLY -std=c99 -pedantic-errors c.c -o c
```

(using gcc 4.8.2 on Linux Mint 17), it compiles with no diagnostic messages and the resulting program prints

```
hello
```

(I use `-pedantic-errors` because that causes gcc to (attempt to) be a conforming ISO C compiler.)

When I drop the `-DASCII_ONLY` option, I get a compile-time error message:

```
c.c: In function ‘main’:
c.c:11:31: error: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type
     char *non_const_message = strstr(message, search_for);
```

The `strstr` function returns a result of type `char*`, *not* `const char*`. It takes two `const char*` arguments, and with the right search string it can return the value of its first argument. This means it can silently discard the `const`ness of its argument. I consider this to be a flaw in the C standard library, but we're probably stuck with it. Conforming C implementations do not have the option of "fixing" this flaw if they want to remain conforming; they can warn about dangerous uses of `strstr` but they can't reject otherwise legal code.

(The flaw could have been avoided by splitting `strstr` into two functions with different names, one taking a `const char*` and returning a `const char*`, and the other taking a `char*` and returning a `char*`. The 1989 ANSI C committee didn't take the opportunity to do this, either because they didn't think of it or because they didn't want to break existing code. C++ addresses it by having two overloaded versions of `strstr`, which was not a possibility for C.)

My first assumption was that gcc is "magically" doing something similar to what C++ does -- but examples that discard `const` using only ASCII characters don't cause a diagnostic message. As my test program shows, the problem is triggered by the use of a non-ASCII character in a string literal (`"Ʃ"` rather than `"h"`).

When I use gcc 4.9.1 (which I installed from source) rather than gcc 4.8.2 (the default version installed on my system), the problem goes away:

```
$ gcc -DASCII_ONLY -std=c99 -pedantic-errors c.c -o c && ./c
hello
$ gcc -std=c99 -pedantic-errors c.c -o c && ./c
c.c: In function ‘main’:
c.c:11:31: error: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type
     char *non_const_message = strstr(message, search_for);
                               ^
$ gcc-4.9.1 -DASCII_ONLY -std=c99 -pedantic-errors c.c -o c && ./c
hello
$ gcc-4.9.1 -std=c99 -pedantic-errors c.c -o c && ./c
non_const_message == NULL
$
```

I haven't tracked down the bug further than that, but you could probably find it in a list of gcc bugs fixed between 4.8.2 and 4.9.1

For the code in the question, you can avoid the problem by defining `pos` as `const char*` rather than `char*`. It should be `const char*` anyway, since it points to an object that was defined as `const`.

Answer (score 7):

A couple of things are going on here.

`gcc`'s header files instruct gcc to use its built-in, optimized `strstr()`, that the compiler knows what it is. Purely from a language standpoint, `strstr()` is just some library function that, in theory, that compiler doesn't know about. But, `gcc` actually knows what it is.

gcc's optimized version of `strstr()` if the string parameter is a `char *`, `strstr()` returns a `char *`; but if the string parameter is a `const char *`, `strstr()` returns a `const char *`, which makes sense.

So, in your case, `strstr()` returns a `const char *`, which results in an obvious error, assigning to a non-const `char *`.

What also appears to be happening is that, in the second part of your question, `gcc` figures out that the string exists, and optimizes the whole thing away; but in that case it should also result in a `const char *` to `char *` conversion, and a warning. Not sure about this one.

Comment: Clang compiles this (once you change the return type of `main`), so it sounds likely.

Comment: You mean that at compilation time, `gcc` somehow knows that the `strstr` call will succeed, looking at the string parameter content ?

Comment: Yeah, gcc's awesome like that.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have an idea why it works with `const char search[] = "é";`?

Comment: `optimized version of strstr()` seems to return `char * NotNULL` or incorrectly `const char *NULL`.

Comment: `strstr()` returns a `char*`, not a `const char*`. (Which means, since it takes `const char*` arguments, that it can be used to quietly discard `const`ness, a flaw in the C standard library.) With `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic-errors`, gcc rejects your code -- which means that gcc does not fully conform to the ISO C standard; it imposes stricter requirements than the language does. I consider this to be a bug in gcc (not conforming by default is ok, not conforming with `-pedantic-errors` is not). There is a real problem in the code: `pos` should be `const char*`, not `char*`.

Comment: There's something more complicated going on here, and the problem appears to be fixed somewhere between gcc 4.8.2 and 4.9.1. See my answer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Following the new answer of KeithThompson I changed the accepted answer as it is more detailed but thanks for your answer : it is a good TL;DR and you already got some nice karma points :)